# Accented characters in Writer

Tags: special-characters

I write in English and French. With word I can use ctrl/modifier + character to get an accented char. eg ctrl/, +c give c with a cedilla. 
Is there an equivalent shortcut in Writer as inserting special characters is too long-winded?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your keyboard layout.

USA International (AltGr dead keys) will allow the usage of AltGr to type accented characters.

When I type AltGr with the letter q through m I get...

äåé®þüúíóö

áßðfghjœø

æx©vbñµ

The composer key can be changed in the keyboard layout too. 
(Compose Key in System > Preferences > Keyboard > Layouts > Other Options)